# ¿Por qué recibo el error "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

No entiendo por qué esta fórmula me devuelve el siguiente error ya que  `str.count("")` en Python devuelve un `int`, y en ningún caso estoy convirtiéndolos en `str`, ¿me pueden ayudar por favor?

```
s = "En un lugar de la Mancha"

def contador_vocales (s):
    s = s.lower()
    vocales = 0
    for vocales in s:
        if "a" in s:
            vocales = vocales + s.count ("a")
        elif "e" in s:
            vocales = vocales + s.count ("e")
        elif "i" in s:
            vocales = vocales + s.count ("i")
        elif "o" in s:
            vocales = vocales + s.count ("o")
        elif "u" in s:
            vocales = vocales + s.count ("u")
    return (vocales)

contador_vocales (s)
```

El error que recibo es:

> vocales = vocales + s.count ("a")
>   TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vocales = 0
for vocales in s:
    ...
```

Primero inicializas la variable vocales a un int, pero después la asignas a un string. Es por eso que te marca error, ya que int + String no es una operación válida.

Siguiendo con la idea de tu código, podrías hacer algo así:

```
def contador_vocales(s):
    v = s.lower()
    return v.count("a") + v.count("e") + v.count("i") + v.count("o") + v.count("u")

print(contador_vocales(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas declarando dos veces la variable "Vocales", que encima iteran por el string sin ningún sentido. Creo que planteaste mal el algoritmo, así creo que te va a servir y va a quedar muchísimo mas claro.

```
s = "En un lugar de la Mancha"

def contador_vocal (s):
    s = s.lower()
    cant_vocales = 0
    vocales = "aeiou"
    for vocal in vocales:
        cant_vocales += s.count(vocal)
    return (cant_vocales)

print (contador_vocal (s))
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Voy a comentar tu código para que veas mas claro lo que sucede.

```
# Declaras una variable de tipo string
s = "En un lugar de la Mancha"

def contador_vocales (s):
    # pasas mayusculas a minusculas
    s = s.lower()
    # declaras una variable de tipo int
    vocales = 0
    # creas una iteración con una variable llamada vocales de tipo string que substituye a la anterior
    for vocales in s:
        if "a" in s:
            # intentas concatenar vocales:str con s.count("a"):int
            vocales = vocales + s.count ("a")
        ...
```

Resumiendo, has reasignado el valor de vocales '0' por un string "a" de ahí el error
Puedes evitarlo cambiando vocales en el bucle for por una variable diferente como vocal

Ejemplo:

```
for vocal in s:
        if "a" in s:
            vocales = vocales + s.count ("a")
            ...
```

otra cosa es que la iteración que haces con el bucle for es del todo innecesaria